# Trouble generating Tabloid (11x17) pdf file from Postscript

Tags: postscript

I have a Postscript file that was intended to be printed on 11x17 paper. But under Mac OSX, the preview program insists on cropping it to letter size. If I actually print it to 11x17 paper, it gets cropped to letter size and then centered in the 11x17 sheet.

(Note that the preview program always converts to pdf as an intermediate step).

Clearly, the generated pdf file is a letter-sized pdf file. I'm guessing that my Postscript file is missing some sort of syntactical sugar to clue the pdf converter as to what the paper size is, but I'm at a loss. I've tried inserting `%%DocumentMedia` and `%%BeginPaperSize` comments into the document at what I take are the right locations, but no effect.

I also tried moving the document to a Linux system, running ps2pdf, and moving the resulting pdf file back to the Mac. No effect. And ps2pdf has never done me wrong before, so that's what makes me think that the problem lies in my Postscript rather than in Apple's pdf converter.

```postscript
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 792 1224
%%Creator: template plugin by Edward Falk
%%DocumentMedia: Tabloid 792 1224 0 () ()
%%Pages: 1
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%EndComments
%%BeginDefaults
%%PageMedia: Tabloid
%%EndDefaults
%%BeginProlog

/drawmarker {       % x y --
  gsave
  translate
  newpath
  0 -0.5 moveto 0 0.5 lineto
  -0.5 0 moveto 0.5 0 lineto
  0 0 .25 0 360 arc
  stroke
  grestore
} bind def

/drawmodel {
  newpath
  86.250 35.750 moveto
  80.536 45.500 lineto
  86.250 35.750 moveto
  103.000 35.750 lineto
  80.536 45.500 moveto
  103.000 45.500 lineto
  103.000 35.750 lineto
  stroke
} bind def

%%EndProlog

%%Page: "1" 1

gsave
72 72 scale
-79.54 -34.75 translate
1 72 div setlinewidth
drawmodel
80.54 35.75 drawmarker
89.54 35.75 drawmarker
80.54 50.75 drawmarker
89.54 50.75 drawmarker
grestore
showpage
%%EndPage: "1" 1

%%EOF
```

Comment: A lot of experimenting and reading indicates that one mistake I made was to have blank lines in the header. Removing those helped (gv now does the right thing), but I'm still not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PostScript doesn't request a page size. Lines beginning '%' are comments in PostScript and don't have any effect (some PostScript consumers will parse DSC comments, which confuses the issue...)

If you want 11x17 media, you need to ask for it:

```
<</PageSize [792 1224]>> setpagedevice
```

Without that you get the default media, whatever that may be. Blank lines are permitted in PostScript and have no effect, a DSC parser which behaves differently with blank lines present is a broken parser, but as I understand it gv is really very old.

Comment: It is indeed. I strongly support that Mac's ps => pdf converter is really ghostscript under the hood, given that the same change fixed both ps2pdf on Linux and Preview on Mac

Comment: Its standard PostScript, if you don't issue a media request you get the default, so I'd expect this to 'fix' any PostScript interpreter. Apologies for the code not coming out right, I've gone back and fixed that.

Comment: p.s. thanks for reminding me that I can define an array with []. It's been ever so long since I last programmed postscript. Is `<< >>` a way of defining dictionaries?

Comment: Yes, in fact << and [ are both equivalent to 'mark', but the closing delimiters determine the type of the object, in effect they do 'dictionary to mark' and 'array to mark'. There was a brief discussion about this on comp.lang.postscript a few months back.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out by reverse-engineering some other files (pdftops is your friend). Documenting my solution here for others who may have the same question in the future.

The missing element wasn't related to DSC, it was actually the `setdevicepage` operator. Adding this code fixed my problem:

```postscript
%%BeginSetup
2 dict begin
/PageSize 792 1224 2 array astore def
/ImagingBBox null def
currentdict end setpagedevice
%%EndSetup
```

If course, doing it right requires testing to see if the setpagedevice function exists, as it was added in language level 2.

Update: simplified using language level 2 features:

```postscript
%%BeginSetup
% set up for pdf
<< /PageSize [792 1224] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice
%%EndSetup
```